# Postgresql subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I need some help with sub querying.
I would like to group by in the first column, then subgroup and sort on a second column, select the MIN, sort on a third column and select the value associated with the MIN from the fourth column.

Something Like this

```
| subject | id | num | code |
|---------|----|-----|------|
| 2       | 34 | 45  | 1234 |
| 2       | 34 | 3   | 1267 |
| 3       | 23 | 32  | 2345 |
| 3       | 23 | 16  | 4568 |
| 3       | 30 | 12  | 5678 |
| 5       | 29 | 53  | 2354 |


| subject | id | num | code |
|---------|----|-----|------|
| 2       | 34 | 3   | 1267 |
| 3       | 23 | 16  | 4568 |
| 5       | 29 | 53  | 2345 |
```

Comment: diid you just change the data or expected result?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No I didn't change the data or expected results. I was trying to make it appear as a table.

Comment: To format as a table just indent each row by 4 chars. there is a button {} in the toolbar which will do it for you as well.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of it, hence the edits

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use [LATERAL subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-table-expressions.html) and ORDER BY xxx LIMIT 1

Live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/71480/6

```
SELECT y.*
FROM (
   SELECT distinct subject
   FROM table1
) x,
LATERAL (
  SELECT * FROM table1 t
  WHERE t.subject = x.subject
  ORDER BY id, num
  LIMIT 1
) y
order by 1
```

---

```
| subject | id | num | code |
|---------|----|-----|------|
|       2 | 34 |   3 | 1267 |
|       3 | 23 |  16 | 4568 |
|       5 | 29 |  53 | 2354 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the row with the minimum(maximum) value is equivalent to finding the rowfor which no row with a lower(higher) value exists:

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM ztable zt
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM ztable nx
        WHERE nx.subject = zt.subject
        AND nx.num < zt.num
        AND nx.id < zt.id
        );
```